# Kafka Consumer not consuming full message

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I have written a kafka consumer process in scala as -

```
executor = endpoint.getCamelContext().getExecutorServiceManager().newFixedThreadPool(
  this, endpoint.getEndpointUri, concurrentConsumers)
ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(executor)
val streams = topicMessageStreams.get(endpoint.topicName).asScala
for (stream <- streams) {
  Future {
    for (messageAndMetaData <- stream) {
      val buffer = messageAndMetaData.message.asInstanceOf[Message].payload
      val bytes = new Array[Byte](buffer.remaining())
      buffer.get(bytes)
      var data = new String(bytes)
      println(data)
    }
  }
}
```

Some times it is consuming partial message only.

i mean suppose broker sends a  message as`{"a":1,"b":2}`
then it is able to consume only `"b":2}` or `"a":1,"b":2}`

what could be the root cause ?

Thanks,

Comment: How are you creating `topicMessageStreams` ? Are you setting any `KeyDecoder` and `ValueDecoder` ?

Comment: From kafka protocol:

    "As an optimization the server is allowed to return a partial message at the end of the message set. Clients should handle this case."

I'm not sure what they mean under "client", would it be driver or application.